# If $S(t)$ is the stock price that satisfies BSM model in SDE form how can I derive an SDE for $S^n (t)$ for some positive integer n

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

If $S(t)$ is the stock price that satisfies BSM model in SDE form where

$dS(t) = \mu S(t) dt + \sigma S(t) d W(t)$ where $\mu >0$ and $\sigma>0$ are two constants.

how can I derive an SDE for $S^n  (t)$ for some positive integer n. Can I say that $S^n (t)$ is a geometric brownian motion?

Would someone mind helping me with this problem, I am studying for a test and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(t)$ be governed by the SDE

$$dS(t)=\mu S(t)dt+\sigma S(t)dW_t$$

Let $f(S)=S^n$.

Heuristically, we can write

$$\begin{align}
d(S^n)&=\frac{\partial f(S)}{\partial t}\,(dt)+\frac{\partial f(S)}{\partial S}\,(dS)+\frac12\frac{\partial ^2f(S)}{\partial S^2}(dS)^2\\\\
&=\frac{\partial S^n}{\partial t}\,(dt)+\frac{\partial S^n}{\partial S}\,(dS)+\frac12\frac{\partial ^2 S^n}{\partial S^2}(dS)^2\\\\
&=(0)\,dt+nS^{n-1}\,(dS)+\frac12 n(n-1)S^{n-2}(dS)^2\\\\
&=\left(n\mu+\frac12 n(n-1)\sigma^2\right)S^n\,dt+n\sigma S^n dW_t \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $S^n$ does follow a GBM process with drift $n\mu+\frac12 n(n-1)\sigma^2$ and diffusion coefficient $n \sigma$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfectly detailed, i think i'm finally starting to get the hang of how to properly use ito lemma. my course notes were not well written so you have been very helpful thank you once again

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  - Mark

Comment: i can't upvote until i have 15 rep! the second im above 15 ill upvote